# How to add header to the backend request using java

Tags: java, http-headers, wso2, wso2-api-manager, api-manager

I'm new with WSO2,I'm trying to add header in the request to my backend, so i done to add it using the calssic method or the xml method as [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM180/Adding+Mediation+Extensions) so now I wanna add it using java method, could you please help me how can make it

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within your class mediator, try to get transport header map from axis2 context and add the new one like [this](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/blob/master/components/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/apimgt/gateway/handlers/security/CORSRequestHandler.java#L245:L247).

```
Map<String, String> headers = (Map) axis2MC.getProperty(
                       org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext.TRANSPORT_HEADERS);

headers.put("NewHeader", "Value");
```

Comment: Thank you bhathiya for your answer could you please tell me how I add this class to api manager

Comment: You can add as a Class mediator or as synapse handler.